# difference between common_type, find_common_type, promote_types, and result_type?

Tags: python, numpy

The numpy library provides many functions, which maybe determine the type of the result of a binary operation.  The ones I found are:

- [common_type()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.common_type.html) - Return a scalar type which is common to the input arrays.
- [find_common_type()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.find_common_type.html) - Determine common type following standard coercion rules.
- [promote_types()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html) - Returns the data type with the smallest size and smallest scalar kind to which both type1 and type2 may be safely cast.
- [result_type()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) - Returns the type that results from applying the NumPy type promotion rules to the arguments.

The descriptions leave me a bit lost.  What are the difference between these functions?  Which function do I use when?

Comment: I haven't used any of them :)   What kind of calculations are you doing where you need to worry about the types?

Comment: @hpaulj I'm trying to write some re-usable function which needs to pre-allocate an empty array to hold the result (using `np.empty()`), and I need to choose the appropriate `dtype` for this.  I tried to read the manual and got confused, so now I'm also curious what the other functions are good for.  And, of course, I still need to find out whether my choice of `result_type()` was correct.

Comment: What possible dtypes are you starting with?

Comment: @hpaulj In my case it's a pair of numeric types, but which ones exactly is of course the caller's choice.